# Displaying all the fields of 'item' sub list of purchase orders in net suite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to display all the fields of 'item' sub list of purchase orders.

Currently I am using the following to fetch value of a specific sublist field.

```
var custcol_landedcost_ir_refno = currentRecord.getSublistValue({
    sublistId : 'item',
    fieldId : 'custcol_landedcost_ir_refno',
    line : i
});
```

here we have more number of fields to display. How can we print all the fields within the 'item' sub list without specifying each and every field like above?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getSublistFields` to fetch a list of fields within a sublist.
[Here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273152943.html) is the documentation for it.
eg

```
var lineItemFieldsList = poRecord.getSublistFields({ sublistId: 'item' });
```